# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'regeneratorRuntime.mark')- React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

react-native: 0.49.5
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
node: 8.6.0

Have this error while running my application. It just started to randomly have problems after I started using proptypes in my react native application (do not think that is the problem).

I tried to comment out my store and proptypes to see if that affects anything and I still get the same error.

Note: I tried removing the caret symbol from my package.json, then removing node_modules, then finally installing again with no effect.

UDPATE:
I did some more digging and got the error to say this :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/christian/Desktop/React-Native/roam/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/package.json'
```

UPDATE:

I removed my node_modules and reinstalled them and now I am getting a similar error but with a different package.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/christian/Desktop/React-Native/roam/node_modules/simple-swizzle/node_modules/is-arrayish/package.json'
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "roam",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.6.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-pages": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-persist-sensitive-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.14",
    "util": "*"
  }
}
```

Pack-lock.json (part of it):

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@babel/code-frame": {
      "version": "7.0.0-beta.51",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.0.0-beta.51.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-vXHZsZKvl435FYKdOdQJRFZDmgw=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@babel/highlight": "7.0.0-beta.51"
      }
    },
    "@babel/highlight": {
      "version": "7.0.0-beta.51",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/highlight/-/highlight-7.0.0-beta.51.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-6IRK4loVlcz9QriWI7Q3bKBtIl0=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "chalk": "^2.0.0",
        "esutils": "^2.0.2",
        "js-tokens": "^3.0.0"
      },

"babel-code-frame": {
      "version": "6.0.15",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-code-frame/-/babel-code-frame-6.0.15.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-UmlpqYXzFaCBFdxi9IxMDz+af7w=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "babel-runtime": "^5.0.0",
        "chalk": "^1.1.0",
        "esutils": "^2.0.2",
        "js-tokens": "^1.0.1",
        "line-numbers": "^0.2.0",
        "repeating": "^1.1.3"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-runtime": {
          "version": "5.8.38",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-runtime/-/babel-runtime-5.8.38.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-HAsC62MxL18If/IEUIJ7QlydTBk=",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "core-js": "^1.0.0"
          }
        },




"babel-core": {
      "version": "6.26.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/-/babel-core-6.26.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-rzL3izGm/O8RnIew/Y2XU/A6C7g=",
      "requires": {
        "babel-code-frame": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-generator": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-helpers": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-messages": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-template": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-traverse": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-types": "^6.26.0",
        "babylon": "^6.18.0",
        "convert-source-map": "^1.5.0",
        "debug": "^2.6.8",
        "json5": "^0.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
        "path-is-absolute": "^1.0.1",
        "private": "^0.1.7",
        "slash": "^1.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.5.6"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-code-frame": {
          "version": "6.26.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-code-frame/-/babel-code-frame-6.26.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-Y/1D99weO7fONZR9uP42mj9Yx0s=",
          "requires": {
            "chalk": "^1.1.3",
            "esutils": "^2.0.2",
            "js-tokens": "^3.0.2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react-native"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env", {"modules": false}], "react-native"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your lock file (eg yarn.lock if you’re using yarn). Do you have both Babel 6 and Babel 7 versions installed? If so - you may need to downgrade dependencies so everything is on version 6.

Comment: Naive question but which one is the correct babel dependency I am looking for? There are many references to babel. For instance, my "@babel/code-frame" is 7.0.0-beta.51. Is that what I am looking for?

Comment: @AaronBrager in my package.json I changed all my babel dependencies to 6 and removed the ^, then I deleted my package-lock.json, reinstalled node_modules. I stlll get a similar error (with a different node package).

Comment: You should be on the 6.x versions of Babel until you are on React Native 0.56, which is the first version to use Babel 7.

Comment: Can you post your updated lock file after downgrading your Babel dependencies?

Comment: I didn't need to downgrade babel, I downgraded react and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of your library is still importing the

```
prop-types
```

from react-native bundle.
You have to correct that.

Comment: That isn't it. I got rid of it, even going back one commit (before I used proptypes, and everything was working) and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by downgrading React to 16.0.0-beta.5